# Running musl apps on glibc system (using libc.so shared library)

Tags: musl

**How can I build and run a program compiled with `musl-gcc` (without static linking) on a glibc based system?**

If I build a simple hello world c program, `objdump -p` only shows libc.so as NEEDED

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libc.so
  ...
```

However, if I add the directory containing musl's libc to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the program still doesn't run. Is it possible to run a program that depends on musl's libc on a glibc-based system?

(I can run programs built with musl with static linkage currently)